# A field extension and equality up to isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, field-theory

If we have in the category of rings two fields $F$ and $F'$ such that $F\hookrightarrow F'$ and $F'\hookrightarrow F$, do we have an isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$ ? If it is not always true, how can one prove the uniqueness up to isomorphism of the rupture field ?

Comment: Do you mean "splitting field"?

Comment: Dear @Zhen, The term "rupture field" is sometimes used to refer to a simple extension $F[x]/(f(x))$ with $f\in F[x]$ irreducible; this is the ``rupture field" of $f$, where we adjoin a single root.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about "rupture fields," assuming you mean field extensions of $F$ obtained by adjoining a root of a single irreducible polynomial, you can prove directly that any two are isomorphic in a unique way. Namely, let $f\in F[x]$ be irreducible and let $(F_1,\alpha_1),(F_2,\alpha_2)$ be ``rupture fields" for $f$ over $F$, meaning (I guess) $F_i$ is an extension of $F$ containing a root $\alpha_i$ of $f$ such that $F_i=F(\alpha)$. There is a unique $F$-algebra map $\varphi_i:F[x]\to F_i$ sending $x$ to $\alpha_i$, and it induces an $F$-algebra isomorphism $F[x]/(f)\simeq F_i$ for $i=1,2$, so by inverting, you get an $F$-algebra isomorphism $F_1\simeq F_2$ sending $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_2$, and it is unique because $\alpha_i$ generates $F_1$ over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

They are not necessarily isomorphic.

Let $F$ be $\overline{\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\ldots)}$, that is, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ after adjoining countably many transcendentals.

Let $F' = F(\alpha_0)$, adjoining one more transcendental but *not* taking an algebraic closure.

Then $F$ injects natively into $F'$, and $F'$ injects into $F$ by mapping $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_{i+2}$ everywhere.

On the other hand they are manifestly not isomorphic because $F'$ contains an element with no square root, but $F$ is algebraically closed.

---

I'm not sure what the "rupture field" would be in this case -- it seems to have something to do with algebraic fields extensions specifically, but here $F'/F$ and $F/F'$ are both transcendental.

Comment: I do not understand why $F'$ injects into $F$ by mapping $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_{i+2}$. Is this injection constant on $\mathbb{Q}$, if so, why does it suffice to define it on $\mathbb{Q}$ and the $\alpha_i$ ? Then, why is $\alpha_0$ transcendental over $F$ ?

Comment: Yes, any homomorphism between characteristic-0 fields has to be constant on $\mathbb Q$, because every rational can be written as $\frac{1+1+\cdots+1}{1+1+\cdots+1}$, so the condition that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ etc fixes its image.

Comment: $a_0$ is transcendental over $F$ _by definition_. In fact, you can consider $F'$ to be the field of fractions of $F[X]$.

Comment: As for defining the injection $F'\to F$, there is a unique homomorphism $\mathbb Q[\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots]\to F$ that sends every $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_{i+2}$ -- that's simply an evaluation map between polynomial rings. By the universal property of fields of fractions, this extends uniquely to an injection $\mathbb Q(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)\to F$. Then by the uniqueness of algebraic closure this extends uniquely to an injection $\overline{\mathbb Q(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)}\to F$. Restricting this to $F'$ gives the desired injection.